# invalid parsing DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS with moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, momentjs

could someone explain me why:
`moment("03-10-2020 12:36:52","DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS", false).isValid()` = FALSE

While

`moment("01-10-2020 08:07:33","DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS", false).isValid()` = TRUE

Comment: because there is no month 36 but there is a month 7 - the docs specify that ***Tokens are case-sensitive.***

Comment: Look at the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/). `MM` stands for Month and not Minute.

Comment: Minutes are parsed via `mm` not `MM`, in other words.

Comment: you may want to change `SS` as well, as they are fractional seconds (whatever a fractional second is)